@UserDefined does not work if the User entity is declared inside an external dependency in Quarkus
I went through this documentation Quarkus Security with Jakarta Persistence. Everything was fine until I moved my entities into an external dependency.
Quarkus generates an io.quarkus.security.jpa.runtime.JpaIdentityProvider in case of existence of io.quarkus.security.jpa.UserDefinition inside the application packages during build time.
There exist a class named io.quarkus.security.jpa.common.deployment.QuarkusSecurityJpaCommonProcessor in
io.quarkus:quarkus-security-jpa-common-deployment:3.8.5

that searches for @UserDefinition annotation inside the Application. This search is done intentionally with a class named io.quarkus.deployment.builditem.ApplicationIndexBuildItem.
Using Jandex helped Hibernate to recognize the entities outside the package but didn’t help ApplicationIndexBuildItem to find the @UserDefinition entity.
So my external entities are not recognized by Quarkus Security Jpa which ends up my application remain unsecure.
Any Idea?
